# extjs4 changing button functionality upon click

Tags: button, extjs4

I have a checkboxgroup with several checkboxes and a button called "Check All' which checks all the checkboxes in the checkboxgroup when clicked. Also when clicked, the text of the button changes to 'Uncheck All'. When the user now clicks this button again, I want all the checkboxes in the checkboxgroup to be unchecked and the button text to change back to 'Check All'. Is this possible with Ext.button.Button or do I need to use Ext.button.Cycle? (NB: the button is wrapped in a panel so that it has access to all the checkboxes in the checkboxgroup)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
Ext.require('*');

Ext.onReady(function(){

    var allChecked = false,
        ignoreChange;

    var onChange = function(){
        if (ignoreChange) {
            return;
        }

        console.log('xxx');
        var checked = true;
        Ext.Array.each(fields, function(field){
            if (!field.checked) {
                checked = false;
                return false;
            }
        });

        allChecked = checked;
        updateButton();
    };

    var updateButton = function(){
        btn.setText(allChecked ? 'Uncheck All' : 'Check All');
    };

    var group = new Ext.form.CheckboxGroup({
        renderTo: document.body,
        columns: 1,
        items: [{
            text: 'A',
            boxLabel: 'A'
        }, {
            text: 'B',
            boxLabel: 'B'
        }, {
            text: 'C',
            boxLabel: 'C'
        }, {
            text: 'D',
            boxLabel: 'D'
        }, {
            text: 'E',
            boxLabel: 'E'
        }, {
            text: 'F',
            boxLabel: 'F'
        }]
    });

    var fields = group.query('checkbox');

    Ext.Array.forEach(fields, function(field){
        field.on('change', onChange);    
    });

    var btn = new Ext.button.Button({
        renderTo: document.body,
        text: 'Check All',
        handler: function(){
            ignoreChange = true;
            Ext.Array.forEach(fields, function(field){
                field.setValue(!allChecked);
            });
            ignoreChange = false;
            allChecked = !allChecked;
            updateButton();
        }
    });

});
```